# Get the HTML Document of WebView2 inside a Thread

Tags: c#, asynchronous, thread-safety, task, webview2

The function should get the HTML Document, working on a Thread.
The ExecuteScriptAsync needs to manage a Task which cause execution error if I run it on a separate thread. I do not know how to get the HTML content synchronously either.
Which would be the best practice solution?

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => Work());
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();

protected void Work()
{
  // ...

  GetHtmlDocument();

  // ...
}

protected string GetHtmlDocument()
{
  if (webBrowserEdge.InvokeRequired)
  {
    return (string)webBrowserEdge.Invoke(
      new Func<String>(() => GetHtmlDocument())
      );
  }
  else
  {
    string script = "document.documentElement.outerHTML";

    return webBrowserEdge.ExecuteScriptAsync(script); // compilation error
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to run a task synchronously? Change `GetHtmlDocument`'s return type to `Task<string>` and use this code in method `Work`:

```cs
using (var task = GetHtmlDocument()) {
  task.RunSynchronously();
  string htmlDocument = task.Result;
}
```

This code runs the task in the thread where it was created (synchronously). The thread is blocked until the task is completed.

Comment: If I return a Task, I do not know the way I can run it inside a Thread without gettin an execution exception. I tried with Task.Run but the same. How could I get the Task result synchronously -the HTML content-, with a blocking calling method?

Comment: @Zelkovar Ah, now I understand your issue. I have completely rewritten my answer. Don't use `await` keyword.

Comment: If then GetHtmlDocument returns a Task<string>, with your function I get the following error: _RunSynchronously may not be called on a task unbound to a delegate_. So my final solution was `string html = task.ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` to get the HTML Document inside my thread without blocking the UI thread.

Comment: OK, I'm glad you solved your problem.